# How large is a fresh install of Python?

Tags: python, installation, filesize

Been looking around, but can't find a hard and fast answer: how large exactly is an install of python, straight from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Edit: currently doing it on a unix system

Comment: I have python 3.4.2 and it's about 65MB

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is going to vary based on which version of Python you're using, which architecture you're downloading for, which installer you have selected (or if you're building from source), etc.

Comment: @machnaimh I would take that to mean the size of the installer itself, which in Windows would typically contain a compressed collection of the installation files. Once extracted and installed, the actual size on disk may be considerably larger, and I'm interpreting this question to mean that is the quantity the OP actually wants to know.

Comment: You mean only base Python and builtin packages (*"battereis not included"*), right? Not third-party packages, installs (like Anaconda), numpy/scipy, numerical, plotting, image packages, Machine Learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

232 megabytes for 3.6.1 (this is a local version that is fully functional) on ubuntu 14.04 and created canonically using

```
.configure 
make   
make install
```

etc.

(i.e. the instructions from the python docs)